# Target positions don't wont in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, antd

In my app I load more data in the select when the scroll position of the select gets to the bottom. I am using Ant Design for the select component and it calls a function when the component is scrolled on. The function that loads more works fine in Chrome but in Safari it doesn't I think because of the way Safari scrolls are handled.

```js
const handleLoadMore = e => {
  if (apiData.context.lastPage) {
    return false;
  }

  e.persist();
  const { target } = e;

  if (target.scrollTop + target.offsetHeight === target.scrollHeight) {
    // This only gets called once when scrolled to the bottom of the select in Chrome,
    // in Safari it gets called more than once causing the same data to be fetched
    fetchMore();
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: You are using Ant Design and the problem involves Safari. You should keep the tags.

Comment: The problem doesnt have anything to do with antd it is just what I am using. The problem is in the scroll events for javascript in safari